# Find All Friends Using Relationships Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

With all the tools and CMS' around it has always been easy for me to create applications. For the first time though I am having to work with advanced SQL with out any ORM, so I don't know how to get the result I'm looking for.

I'm trying to make a user-friends system. Basically a user can add another user as friend, the friended user can accept. I have two tables Users & Users_Relationships. The Users table has the obvious, user information and User_Relationships table has relation_setter (the requester user's id), relation_getter (the requested user's id) and active

The problem is I need to display all Friends (active or inactive) on a page. I know the following query is wrong, but this is what I've come up with:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM users_relationships
        LEFT JOIN users
        ON users_relationships.relation_setter = users.user_id
        WHERE users_relationships.relation_getter = " . $logged_in_id.
      " OR users_relationships.relation_setter = " . $logged_in_id;
```

What I need is all the users that are in the relationship table as the setter or getter with the $logged_in_user. Simply I need all the people I'm friends with, regardless of who has added them, me or them and based on the 'active' value I got for each row, it will print "Request Pending" or not.

The above query is bringing me very mixed results with many duplicates with the request pending also wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the table `Users` one more time like this:

```
SELECT 
  us.UserName AS SetterName,
  ug.UserName AS GetteerName,
  ur.Active AS Status,
  ...
FROM users_relationships ur
LEFT JOIN users us ON ur.relation_setter = us.user_id
LEFT JOIN users ug ON ur.relation_getter = ug.user_id 
WHERE $logged_in_id IN(ur.relation_getter, ur.relation_setter);
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b152/1)

---

### Update 1

In order to get the list of friends as one list instead of two users' names, you can do this:

```
SELECT 
  us.UserName AS FriendName,
  ur.Active AS Status
FROM 
(
  SELECT relation_setter user_id, active 
  FROM users_relationships
  WHERE relation_getter = $logged_in_id 
  UNION  
  SELECT relation_getter, active 
  FROM users_relationships
  WHERE relation_setter = $logged_in_id 
) AS ur
LEFT JOIN users us ON ur.user_id = us.user_id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b152/6)

This will give you a list of friends names of the logged in user.

---

### Update 2

**How this query works?**

The list of the logged in use is either a `relation_setter` or `relation_getter`. So in order to get these two in one column, I get each one of them using two queries, one for `relation_setter`:

```
  SELECT relation_setter user_id, active 
  FROM users_relationships
  WHERE relation_getter = $logged_in_id
```

And the other for `relation_getter`:

```
  SELECT relation_getter, active 
  FROM users_relationships
  WHERE relation_setter = $logged_in_id
```

Then I used **[`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)** to get them as one result set:

```
  SELECT relation_setter user_id, active 
  FROM users_relationships
  WHERE relation_getter = $logged_in_id 
  UNION  
  SELECT relation_getter, active 
  FROM users_relationships
  WHERE relation_setter = $logged_in_id
```

This query will give us all the data from the two queries into only two fields `user_id`, `active`.

**Note that:**

- `UNION` is implicitly select distinct rows, it will eliminate duplicate rows, but `UNION ALL` will keep those duplicate rows.
- The two unioned result set will have the columns' names that are specified in the first select; in our query, the second select has the first column with the name `relation_getter` the values coming from this column will be under the `userid` because it is defined in the first query.

Then I enclosed this two unioned queries inside a subquery and joined it with the `Users` table, and we are done :)

Comment: Thanks a lot of the answer. In this case though we get two usernames because we are joining the tables twice. Correct? which is why it includes logged_in_user twice and some duplicates. How do I get a friends like any usual social network? Thanks again

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't understand it, but I'm going to, eventually.

Comment: You Sir, have saved me so much grief. I solved two issues in my app with your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Aayush - You're welcome any time :) I edited my answer, hope it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM users_relationships rel
        LEFT outer JOIN users from  ON rel.relation_setter = from.user_id
        LEFT outer JOIN users to ON rel.relation_getter = to.user_id
        WHERE rel.relation_getter in (" . $logged_in_id. "," . $logged_in_id . ")";
```